# DDMS and os show different memory info about my app

Tags: android, memory-leaks, ddms

I'm working with the ddms to find memory leaks and other bugs. 
When tracking the memory I see a heap size of 30MB.

But when I go to device and check the memory in the application manager I see 70 MB.

Is it normal?
What's the reason for this ?

Device : SamsunGalaxy GT9300

Comment: Is this running Android 4.0 or Android 2.3?

Answer (score 4):

Yes its normal, DDMS shows only running app memory. You can also try another tool like
memory analyser tool(MAT). You see best result comparison to DDMS.

[Here is the link](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html).

Comment: @Satyam, can you stop indenting your prose as code-blocks? By now you should already have a good grasp of the available formatting in answers